# how does microservice architecture with sync communication scales?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, microservices

Suppose I have two services book service and order service.

Book service gives information about books - name, id, publishing house, summary, author etc - basically finding books for the user based on some query, it may also use Machine learning. It has one endpoint /books/search which takes some query and gives out results.

Order service helps in creating an order using userid and book id. It also has one endpoint /order/create.

There is one relational database, which holds books, orders and users. It also has some read replicas to make querying faster for book service. I have a books.js file for book service, which I deployed on EC2 instance and order.js file which I deployed on another EC2 instance.

There is a api gateway which forwards the request to appropriate EC2 instance.

Suppose the traffic on books service increase drastically, how do I scale the book service programmatically? does AWS API Gateway help in that?

if from the start I deployed multiple instances of books service, lets say 3 instances, can they have the same address and port so that API gateway forward user request easily OR they need to have different address and port. Does API gateway has the capability to load balance the requests to book service EC2 instances or will I need to add a load balancer also?

I understand how scaling with async communication is done - basically you have a queue from SQS, there is EC2 instance that monitors the queue and spins up or down the EC2 instances based on size of the queue. There is some place to store the status of EC2 instances based on which the monitor instance scales down the instances. The created instances take messages from the SQS queue, do the processing, store the result somewhere, sends the notification like email to the user.

In this however the user doesnt get the response immediately. I want the user to get immediate response.

Kindly answer the question without using function service like lambda or docker service like ECS as I don't understand them fully.

Also, can anyone point to some good resources to learn about microservices with nodeJS and AWS. When I tried to find such resources, I found them to be very high level and not really talking in step by step manner.

Comment: `point to some good resources to learn..` This is out of scope of a single question and asking to find resources is not encouraged on SO. Please try to focus your question to a single specific programming/technical question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose the traffic on books service increase drastically, how do I scale the book service programmatically?

You don't need to scale the service *programatically*. The default way is to place the service instance into an [autoscaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html) and place an internal load balancer in front of the autoscaling group. Now the  task would be to find the proper metrics to scale the service.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/03/api-gateway-private-integrations-aws-elb-cloudmap-http-apis-release/

> does AWS API Gateway help in that?

Actually it may, depends on.. The API GW could provide additional metrics you could use to scale the service, but I'm not sure how useful the metrics will be for your case

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-metrics.html